# Trying to find de-duplicated rows using ROW_NUMBER / PARTITION BY

Tags: sql

Trying to find unique rows of field a.id.  I think I need a sub-qry somewhere but not sure how to pull that off. Any help?

```
 SELECT  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY a.id
        ORDER BY a.id
        ) row_num,
        a.id
        a.firstname, 
    FROM table1 a 
    WHERE convert(date, a.InsertDate) = convert(date, getdate()-3)
    AND country = 'US'
    AND reg in ('abc','def')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter, then a subquery is one possibility:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.idORDER BY a.id) as row_num,
              a.id, a.firstname, 
      FROM table1 a 
      WHERE convert(date, a.InsertDate) = convert(date, getdate()-3) AND
            country = 'US'
            reg in ('abc', 'def')
    ) a
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

If performance is not an issue (because this is a tad slower), you can also put the `ROW_NUMBER()` in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.idORDER BY a.id) as row_num,
        a.id, a.firstname, 
FROM table1 a 
WHERE convert(date, a.InsertDate) = convert(date, getdate()-3) AND
      country = 'US'
      reg in ('abc', 'def')
ORDER BY row_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query for your problem...

```
With CTE 
AS
(
 SELECT  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY a.id
        ORDER BY a.id
        ) row_num,
        a.id
        a.firstname
    FROM table1 a 
    WHERE convert(date, a.InsertDate) = convert(date, getdate()-3)
    AND country = 'US'
    AND reg in ('abc','def')

)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE row_Num=1
```